# calling classmethod using 'self'?

Tags: python, class-method

```
class Hello:
    def load(self):
        self.open('World')
    @classmethod
    def open(cls,print_string):
        print 'Hello ' + print_string


class Hello:
    def load(self):
        Hello.open('World')
    @classmethod
    def open(cls,print_string):
        print 'Hello ' + print_string
```

I am finding difficult to understand from above two classes different style of calling class method. One uses self and another class name while calling, when should one use first and when should the second be used?

Good explanation will really clarify `@classmethod` concept.

Answer (score 5):

The issue at heart here really isn't `classmethod`, it is how Python handles attributes. There are two different kinds of attributes, class-level attributes (in other languages sometimes called "static" attributes) and instance attributes.

Consider:

```
>>> class A:
...    a = 'foo'
...    def __init__(self):
...       self.x = 42
...    def method(self):
...       print(A.a)
...       print(self.a)
...       print(self.x)
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.method()
foo
foo
42
```

Now, in Python, class-level attributes (which includes methods themselves) belong to the *class namespace*, accessible via the `__dict__` attribute:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(A.__dict__)
mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'A' objects>,
              '__doc__': None,
              '__init__': <function A.__init__ at 0x101589d90>,
              '__module__': '__main__',
              '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>,
              'a': 'foo',
              'method': <function A.method at 0x10863a620>})
```

The *instance* attributes are *only* those you explicitly assign to an instance using `self.something = somethingsomething`:

```
>>> pprint(a.__dict__)
{'x': 42}
```

However, when you *access* an attribute, you can think that Python *first* checks the `__dict__` of the instance. If it doesn't find it, it then checks the namespace of the *class*. If it *still doesn't find it*, it checks the namespaces of any parent-classes in the method-resolution order (i.e. inheritance).

So, classes being simply other objects themselves, if you do:

```
Hello.open('World')
```

This checks the `Hello` objects namespace and finds it. Similarly, if you use the method on the instance,

```
self.open('World')
```

It checks the instances namespace, doesn't find it, then checks the classes namespace and does. Now, if you don't expect to extend the class, then there really isn't a difference. But if you *do* then the semantics will change. If you derive from `Hello`, and override `open` and not `load`, the `Hello.open` will *always call the super-classes `open` method*. However, the `self.open` version will find it in the classes namespace, and never check the parent classes. So, depending on exactly the behavior you want, you can use either, but usually if you class is designed correctly then `self` is the way to go. But maybe not. So, to give you a concrete example:

```
>>> class B(A):
...    a = 'bar'
...
>>> b = B()
>>> b.method()
foo
bar
42
>>>
```

Comment: Hi juanpa if method-resolution order is the case then why don't we define everything at instance level and then we need have @classmethod.

Comment: @PravinAgre Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking. What do you mean defined at the instance level, you mean *access* at the instance level?

Comment: Hey Juanpa......cleared the doubt.......understood when to use self with class and when not to. Thanks a lot for your Great explanation.